# Extract the date written inside the body of the mail using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I have been assigned a task to save the outlook attachments received daily and rename them with the date written inside the mail. The code will be running in outlook vba. I am able to save attachments but stuck with rename of the folder. The folders will be saved in H drive. How should i extract the date from the body of the mail and name the folder with that date using vba. Thank u for the help

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you managed to access the body text of the email?  Have you looked up how to rename a folder or file using VBA?  StackOverflow is not a code-writing or homework-completing service; we will be very happy to answer *specific* issues, preferably with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item..
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.